# javaFX tableview auto scroll to last

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to java/javaFX so be patient with me.

The problem I'm having is that I don't get auto scrolling to work.

I've tried these solutions but didn't get them to work:

[javafx tableview auto scroll to the last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779135/javafx-tableview-auto-scroll-to-the-last)

[JavaFX how to add ChangeListener to auto scroll TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972021/javafx-how-to-add-changelistener-to-auto-scroll-tableview)

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("DogRegister.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setMinHeight(900);
            stage.setMinWidth(1200);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setTitle("Dog Registry");
            Image image = new Image("/image/paw.png");
            stage.getIcons().add(image);
            stage.show();

            stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
                event.consume();
                exit(stage);
            });

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void exit(Stage stage){

        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alert.setTitle("Exit");
        alert.setHeaderText("You're about to exit!");
        alert.setContentText("Are you sure you want to exit?: ");

        if(alert.showAndWait().get() == ButtonType.OK){
            System.out.println("You successfully exited!");
            stage.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;



public class DogRegisterController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML
    private TableView<Dog> dogTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Dog, Integer> idCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Dog, String> nameCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Dog, String> BreedCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Dog, Integer> ageCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Dog, Integer> weightCol;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Dog, Double> tailCol;

    @FXML
    private TextField idField;
    @FXML
    private TextField nameField;
    @FXML
    private TextField breedField;
    @FXML
    private TextField ageField;
    @FXML
    private TextField weightField;

    @FXML
    private Button removeBtn;
    @FXML
    private Button submitBtn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, Integer>("id"));
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, String>("name"));
        BreedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, String>("breed"));
        ageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, Integer>("age"));
        weightCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, Integer>("weight"));
        tailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Dog, Double>("tailLength")); 

        setupTable();
    }

    @FXML
    void submit(ActionEvent event){
        Dog dog = new Dog(nameField.getText(), breedField.getText(),
                        Integer.parseInt(ageField.getText()), Integer.parseInt(weightField.getText()));
        ObservableList<Dog> dogs = dogTable.getItems();
        dogs.add(dog);
        dogTable.setItems(dogs);
    }

    @FXML
    void edit(ActionEvent event){
        ObservableList<Dog> currentTableData = dogTable.getItems();
        int currentDogId = Integer.parseInt(idField.getText());

        for(Dog dog : currentTableData){
            if(dog.getId() == currentDogId) {
                dog.setId(Integer.parseInt(idField.getText()));
                dog.setName(nameField.getText());
                dog.setBreed(breedField.getText());
                dog.setAge(Integer.parseInt(ageField.getText()));
                dog.setWeight(Integer.parseInt(weightField.getText()));

                dogTable.setItems(currentTableData);
                dogTable.refresh();
                idField.clear();
                nameField.clear();
                breedField.clear();
                ageField.clear();
                weightField.clear();
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    @FXML
    void rowClicked(MouseEvent event){
        Dog clickedDog = dogTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        
        idField.setText(String.valueOf(clickedDog.getId()));
        nameField.setText(String.valueOf(clickedDog.getName()));
        breedField.setText(String.valueOf(clickedDog.getBreed()));
        ageField.setText(String.valueOf(clickedDog.getAge()));
        weightField.setText(String.valueOf(clickedDog.getWeight()));
    }


    @FXML
    void removeDog(ActionEvent event){
        int selectedID = dogTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        dogTable.getItems().remove(selectedID);
        idField.clear();
        nameField.clear();
        breedField.clear();
        ageField.clear();
        weightField.clear();
        dogTable.refresh();
    }

    public static <S> void addAutoScroll(final TableView<S> dogTable) {
        if (dogTable == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    
        dogTable.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener<S>) (c -> {
            c.next();
            final int size = dogTable.getItems().size();
            if (size > 0) {
                dogTable.scrollTo(size - 1);
            }
        }));
    }


    private void setupTable(){
        Dog dog0 = new Dog("Luna", "Eurasier", 3, 22);
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Skye", "Dachshund", 4, 5);
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Bella", "Dachs", 2, 3);
        Dog dog3 = new Dog("Sky", "Tax", 3, 3);

        dogTable.getItems().addAll(dog0, dog1, dog2, dog3);
    }
}
```

Dog.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Dog {

    private static final AtomicInteger _ID = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private int age;
    private int weight;
    private double tailLength;
    private int id;

    public Dog(String name, String breed, int age, int weight){
        this.id = _ID.incrementAndGet();
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.tailLength = getTailLength();
    }

    public double getTailLength(){

        if (breed.toLowerCase().equals("tax") || breed.toLowerCase().equals("dachshund")|| breed.toLowerCase().equals("dachs")){
            return 3.7;
        } else {
            return (age * weight) / 10.0;
        }
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    
    public void setId(int id){ this.id = id; }
    
    public String getName() { return name; }
    
    public void setName(String name){ this.name = name; }

    public String getBreed() { return breed; }

    public void setBreed(String breed){this.breed = breed;}
    
    public int getWeight() { return weight; }

    public void setWeight(int weight) { this.weight = weight; }
    
    public int getAge() { return age; }

    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
}
```

GUI.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="mainPane" minHeight="900.0" minWidth="1200.0" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1200.0" styleClass="pane" stylesheets="@StyleSheet.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="DogRegisterController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="dogTable" layoutX="586.0" layoutY="160.0" onMouseClicked="#rowClicked" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="600.0" stylesheets="@StyleSheet.css" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="60.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="100.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="idCol" minWidth="50.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="ID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="nameCol" minWidth="140.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="BreedCol" minWidth="140.0" prefWidth="140.0" text="Breed" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="ageCol" minWidth="80.0" text="Age" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="weightCol" minWidth="80.0" text="Weight" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="tailCol" minWidth="96.0" prefWidth="96.0" text="Tail-length" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
         <styleClass>
            <String fx:value="column-header" />
            <String fx:value="column-header-background" />
            <String fx:value="corner" />
            <String fx:value="filler" />
            <String fx:value="table-cell" />
            <String fx:value="table-row-cell" />
            <String fx:value="table-view" />
         </styleClass>
      </TableView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="100.0" fitWidth="150.0" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="100.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@image/paw.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <VBox prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="560.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="ID" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" right="100.0" top="260.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <TextField fx:id="idField" editable="false" prefHeight="35.0" styleClass="text-field" stylesheets="@StyleSheet.css">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="100.0" right="100.0" top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextField>
            <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Name" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" right="100.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <TextField fx:id="nameField" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="35.0" styleClass="text-field" stylesheets="@StyleSheet.css">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="100.0" right="100.0" top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextField>
            <Text layoutX="10.0" layoutY="39.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Breed" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" right="100.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <TextField fx:id="breedField" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="127.0" prefHeight="35.0" styleClass="text-field" stylesheets="@StyleSheet.css">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="100.0" right="100.0" top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextField>
            <Text layoutX="10.0" layoutY="57.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Age" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" right="100.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <TextField fx:id="ageField" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="144.0" prefHeight="35.0" styleClass="text-field" stylesheets="@StyleSheet.css">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="100.0" right="100.0" top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextField>
            <Text layoutX="10.0" layoutY="71.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Weight" textAlignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="100.0" right="100.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Text>
            <TextField fx:id="weightField" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="160.0" prefHeight="35.0" styleClass="text-field" stylesheets="@StyleSheet.css">
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="100.0" right="100.0" top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </TextField>
            <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <Button fx:id="submitBtn" alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#submit" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="140.0" stylesheets="@../../Assignment-3/src/style.css" text="Submit">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="25.0" right="25.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
                  <Button fx:id="editBtn" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#edit" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="140.0" stylesheets="@../../Assignment-3/src/style.css" text="Edit">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="25.0" right="25.0" top="10.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </Button>
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="100.0" right="100.0" top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <Button fx:id="removeBtn" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="770.0" layoutY="825.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#removeDog" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="140.0" stylesheets="@../../Assignment-3/src/style.css" text="Remove" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="35.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Hello :) Could you please give us a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? At least we would like to see the problematic code.

Comment: Review these related [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+TableView++scrollTo) and [edit] your question to show your revised approach.

Comment: Your `addAutoScroll` method is never called.  You can delete the method and move its code into the `setupTable` method (it won't need the null check then because the table must not be null for the setup to work).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got it working thanks to @jewelsea

had forgotten to add "addAutoScroll(dogTable)" to setupTable method so the auto scroll was never called.

Controller.java

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;



public class DogRegisterController implements Initializable {
    
    public static <S> void addAutoScroll(final TableView<S> dogTable) {
        if (dogTable == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    
        dogTable.getItems().addListener((ListChangeListener<S>) (c -> {
            c.next();
            final int size = dogTable.getItems().size();
            if (size > 0) {
                dogTable.scrollTo(size - 1);
            }
        }));
    }


    private void setupTable(){
        Dog dog0 = new Dog("Luna", "Eurasier", 3, 22);
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Skye", "Dachshund", 4, 5);
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Bella", "Dachs", 2, 3);
        Dog dog3 = new Dog("Sky", "Tax", 3, 3);

        dogTable.getItems().addAll(dog0, dog1, dog2, dog3);

        addAutoScroll(dogTable);
    }
}
```

Comment: refresh is wrong..

Comment: You should consider explaining in a few sentences what the problem was at the beginning of the answer rather than copy-pasting the entire code.